# Setting up JimFlow on a local machine

Tags: python, local, scrumboard

i'am trying to set up JimFlow(http://jimflow.jimdo.com/).

I managed to setup nearly everything, but im facing a problem with JimFlowKlopfer ( it's a python script, that scans QR-Codes and output a JSON file), because i dont know much about Python and my google searches didnt help me im asking now you :-)

Im always getting this error when the script is trying to scan the QR-Code:

```
python -m jimflowklopfer.__main__ ~/Dokumente/projekte/work/qrCodes/ ~/Dokumente/projekte/work/output


list index out of range
```

I dont know what "index out of range" mean in this case.

Would be nice if someone can help me or give me a hint what the problem can be :-)

greetz

Comment: show us the part of the code who fails (see stacktrace)

Answer (score 0):

i think when im posting it here, it looks better :-P

```
import zbar
import Image
import ImageDraw
import kanban

class Scanner(object):
    def __init__(self, imagepath):
        self.image = Image.open(imagepath).convert('L')
        self.width, self.height = self.image.size
        self.informations = []
        # create a reader
        self.scanner = zbar.ImageScanner()
        # configure the scanner
        self.scanner.set_config(0, zbar.Config.ENABLE, 0)
        self.scanner.set_config(zbar.Symbol.QRCODE, zbar.Config.ENABLE, 1)

def image_optimize(self):
    doubled_size = (self.image.size[0] * 2, self.image.size[1] * 2)
    self.image = self.image.resize(doubled_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    self.width, self.height = self.image.size

def scan(self):
    self.image_optimize()
    pieces_size = int(self.get_qr_code_size() * 2)
    step_size = int(pieces_size / 4)
    self.scan_image(self.image,0,0)
    y_start = 0

    iy = 0
    while y_start < self.height:
        y_start = iy * step_size
        y_end = y_start + pieces_size
        iy += 1
        ix = 0
        x_start = 0
        while x_start < self.width:
            x_start = ix * step_size
            x_end = x_start + pieces_size
            crop_to = (x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end)
            img_crop = self.image.crop(crop_to)
            self.scan_image(img_crop, x_start, y_start)
            ix += 1

    return self.informations

def get_qr_code_size(self):
    zbar_img = zbar.Image(self.width, self.height, 'Y800', self.image.tostring())php

    qr_sizes = []

    print(qr_sizes)
    # scan the image for barcodes
    self.scanner.scan(zbar_img)
    for symbol in zbar_img:
        qr_width = symbol.location[3][0] - symbol.location[0][0]
        qr_height = symbol.location[1][1] - symbol.location[0][1]
        qr_sizes.append(qr_width)
        qr_sizes.append(qr_height)
    if len(qr_sizes) == 0:
        raise IOError('Klopfer says: no qr code scanned')

    return sum(qr_sizes, 0.0) / len(qr_sizes)

def scan_image(self, img_scan, x_start, y_start):
    crop_width, crop_height = img_scan.size
    zbar_img = zbar.Image(crop_width, crop_height, 'Y800', img_scan.tostring())

    # scan the image for barcodes
    self.scanner.scan(zbar_img)

    # Create a draw object
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(self.image)
    draw_crop = ImageDraw.Draw(img_scan)

    for symbol in zbar_img:
        top_left = (symbol.location[0][0] + x_start, symbol.location[0][1] + y_start)
        bottom_left = (symbol.location[1][0] + x_start, symbol.location[1][1] + y_start)
        bottom_right = (symbol.location[2][0] + x_start, symbol.location[2][1] + y_start)
        top_right = (symbol.location[3][0] + x_start, symbol.location[3][1] + y_start)
        self.informations.append(kanban.Information(symbol.data, (top_left, bottom_left, bottom_right, top_right)))
        draw.rectangle([(top_left), (bottom_right)], fill="black")
        draw_crop.rectangle([symbol.location[0], symbol.location[2]], fill="black")
    if len(zbar_img.symbols) > 0:
        self.scan_image(img_scan, x_start, y_start)
```

this is the scanner.py, i think there it breaks. I just realized that the things i import (zbar, Image, ImageDraw) are red underlined, but i installed the packages, should i put the package into the project? or is it enough when i just install them.